# WindowService to send autometic SMS but it is doesn't works for me

Tags: c#, windows-services

> I am trying to send SMS automatically by using WindowsService but i
>   don't know what is going wrong and missing in in below code
>
> i got this Service Code from another site.. can anyone help to know
>   about what is going wrong in this code..
>
> Source site :
>   https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Automatically-send-Birthday-email-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>
        <!-- <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>-->
        <add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="1"/>
        <add key ="ScheduledTime" value ="10:46 AM"/>
    </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=mahidb.cjdtlepfduxv.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com;Initial Catalog=PerfectMonitorApp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mahiadmin;Password=***********" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

> and the below code is for send SMS Automatically

**Service1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsServiceCS
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");
            this.ScheduleService();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.WriteToFile("Simple Service stopped {0}");
            this.Schedular.Dispose();
        }

        private Timer Schedular;

        public void ScheduleService()
        {
            try
            {
                Schedular = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback));
                string mode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mode"].ToUpper();
                this.WriteToFile("Simple Service Mode: " + mode + " {0}");

                //Set the Default Time.
                DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                if (mode == "DAILY")
                {
                    //Get the Scheduled Time from AppSettings.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduledTime"]);
                    if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                    {
                        //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next day.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
                    }
                }

                if (mode.ToUpper() == "INTERVAL")
                {
                    //Get the Interval in Minutes from AppSettings.
                    int intervalMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntervalMinutes"]);

                    //Set the Scheduled Time by adding the Interval to Current Time.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
                    if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                    {
                        //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next Interval.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
                    }
                }

                TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                string schedule = string.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hour(s) {2} minute(s) {3} seconds(s)", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

                this.WriteToFile("Simple Service scheduled to run after: " + schedule + " {0}");

                //Get the difference in Minutes between the Scheduled and Current Time.
                int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

                //Change the Timer's Due Time.
                Schedular.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

                //Stop the Windows Service.
                using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("SimpleService"))
                {
                    serviceController.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        //private void SchedularCallback(object e)
        //{
        //    this.WriteToFile("Simple Service Log: {0}");
        //    this.ScheduleService();
        //}

        private void WriteToFile(string text)
        {
            string path = "C:\\ServiceLog.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

        private void SchedularCallback(object e)
        {
            try
            {


                        string message1 = "Demo Birthday Message from Divine Infoservices";
                        string mob = "9033389555";
                        string sAPIKey = "hiu7y6nhgh7hnkj";
                        string sNumber = mob;
                        string sMessage = message1;
                        string sSenderID = "ABABAB";
                        string sChannel = "Trans";
                        string sRoute = "15";
                        //string sURL = "http://dnd.saakshisoftware.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKEY=" + sAPIKey + "&senderid=" + sSenderID + "&channel=" + sChannel + "&DCS=0&flashsms=0&number=" + sNumber + "&text=" + sMessage + "&route=" + sRoute + ";";
                        try
                        {
                            string sURL = "http://dnd.saakshisoftware.com/api/mt/SendSMS?user=adcadc&password=123456&senderid=abcgnr&channel=trans&DCS=0&flashsms=0&number=" + sNumber + "&text=" + sMessage + "&route=15";
                            string sResponse = GetResponse(sURL);
                            //Console.Write(sResponse);
                            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
                            request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
                            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                            try
                            {
                                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream(
                                );
                                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                                // string sResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                                response.Close();
                                readStream.Close();
                                //return sResponse;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //return ex.ToString();
                            }


                        }
                        catch (SystemException ex)
                        {

                        }

                    this.ScheduleService();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

                //Stop the Windows Service.
                using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("SimpleService1"))
                {
                    serviceController.Stop();
                }
            }

        }
        public static string GetResponse(string sURL)
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream(
                );
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string sResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
                return sResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your service process running in taskmanager? as you are using Timer that won't tick until your process is live in memory so you will be in need to set task to run on windows startup

Comment: Yes it is running Successfully in My "Windows Logs" and also in "Services".. @Technacron

Comment: can you please log the exceptions occurring in SchedularCallback ( if any ) in log file

Comment: i just got this error in windows logs "Service cannot be started. The service process could not connect to the service controller" @Technacron